# R Markdown chunk font color changed

Tags: r, colors, r-markdown, chunks

Just a few days ago, when I create a R Markdown, the chunk colors were like this

[image: Before]

now it looks like this

[image]

The function calls are lack of color. Why is that? now it feels so "colorless"...

Comment: Compare like with like, please. Use quoted strings, %in% and %>% operators, ifelse, etc Also helpful to add the version of rmarkdown packages used before and now.

Comment: I've edited so you can see the difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change syntax highlighting in the Yaml options of an R Markdown document:

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: breezedark
---

Some Test code:

```{r results='hide'}
library(tidyr)
relig_income %>%
  pivot_longer(!religion, names_to = "income", values_to = "count")
```
````

[image]

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: pygments
---

Some Test code:

```{r results='hide'}
library(tidyr)
relig_income %>%
  pivot_longer(!religion, names_to = "income", values_to = "count")
```
````

[image]

Supported styles include `default`, `tango`, `pygments`, `kate`, `monochrome`, `espresso`, `zenburn`, `haddock`, `breezedark`, and `textmate` ([Source](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#appearance-and-style)). It's not clear why the style changed for you, but I think you have to find that out yourself :)

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly. Actually, I've noticed that `tango` is now the same as `default` I don't know why! I've tried both and are the same. It's like `default` has been deleted or something. Anyway, thanks this solves my problem :). By the way, `textmate` doesn't seem to exist... at least on my version of RStudio (the newest one by this date) It's a little bit weird. Thanks again!

Comment: `tango` and `default` look quite different for me. And neither one looks like your screenshots! The styles are translated into actual colours by pandoc. So the change was probably there, but I'm unwilling to dig further...

Comment: Very nice. In my case, for reasons unknown, I had to remove the indent of `highlight: pygments`, that is I had to align it with `html_document:` above it. Otherwise I got an instant crash.